# Meteor, how to access to a helper from another helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a helper like

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
  user:function() {
     return Meteor.users.find({'profile.front_name':Session.get('slug')}).fetch()[0];
  }
});
```

I want to add a helper to the collection which could access the `user` helper and compare its `_id` with the current user `_id`, to tell whether the user is visiting its own profile.
I'm using something pretty ugly:

```
Template.user_profile._tmpl_data.helpers.user()
```

The final code:

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
  user:function() {
     return Meteor.users.find({'profile.front_name':Session.get('userId')}).fetch()[0];
  },
  isCurrentUser: function() {
    return Template.user_profile._tmpl_data.helpers.user()._id === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Is there any better way to access another helper?

Answer (score 34):

I've just accidentally discovered this in the console:

```
Template.registerHelper
function (name, func) {                                                                             
  Blaze._globalHelpers[name] = func;                                                                                   
}
```

So, `Blaze._globalHelpers` is what we are looking for!

Comment: Finally found a real answer among all the google results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You can call a template helper (not global helper - which is in outluch's answer) with:

```
Template.tplName.__helpers.get('helper').call()
```

MDG suggests using a regular function and then passing it to helpers, events and so on. See [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4732#issuecomment-121419193).

**Update 16.06.16**
Actually I strongly advise to simply use [manuel:viewmodel](https://atmospherejs.com/manuel/viewmodel) - it alleviates so many Blaze headaches...

Answer (score 4):

As I was searching for a way to call a helper from another helper, I found that Meteor 1.0 defines "Template.registeredHelpers" that are available for all other helpers to use. https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

```
Template.registerHelper("checkedIf",function(value){
  return value?"checked":"";
});
```

Comment: I tried to use Template.registerHelper in a separate helper.js file holding all the such helpers, but when I try to invoke it in another template event it doesnt help. So question is can such helpers be invoked in events?

`
Template.registerHelper("checkedIf",function(value){
  return value?"checked":"";
});

Template.myform.events({
    "submit .js-save-element: function(event) {
          console.log('Invoking helper: ' + checkedIf('teststring'));
    }
});
`

here I get error `ReferenceError: checkedIf is not defined.`

Comment: Hey, I think there's a confusion on what is a helper here. A helper is a fonction that is called from the template (ie, the .html file when using Blaze). You cannot access the helpers (that feeds information into your template) from an event (that process information coming out of the template).

One hacky way could be to call Blaze._globalHelpers['checkedIf']() but as it is an 'undocumented"/ internal feature, it may not be supported in future release. 

What about defining your method outside of the template system (global or file-scoped) and simply call it from both the places you need it?

Comment: actually I ended up doing something like that only - old school way. In my utils.js I just defined a global scoped function and then I can invoke it in both - helper & events. I was more thinking in terms of how-to-do-it-meteor-way? (if any). Anyway thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You might not even need to call a helper like that.  There is a currentUser helper already built in.

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser

```
{{currentUser}}
```

Comment: I want to check whether the profile the user is visiting is its own.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would work for you:

```
  //js
Template.foo.helpers({ bar: function() {
 return this.userId == Meteor.userId(); },
 domain: function() {
 var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = this.url;
 return a.hostname;
 } });

 ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) { return doc && doc.userId === userId;}

 Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
 Posts.allow({
 update: ownsDocument, remove: ownsDocument
 });

  //html
{{#if bar}}<a href="{{pathFor 'postEdit'}}">Edit</a>{{/if}}
```

Comment: (for checking if user visits his own --> first part and html), and then if you would allow edit, the second part