# Meteor - is there any way to access helper from another helper

Tags: meteor

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229302/meteor-how-to-access-to-an-helper-from-another-helper). But this is not what I want.

```
Template.testTemp.helpers({
    firstValue: function () {
        return something
    },

    secondValue: function () {
        // I want to access firstValue here.
        // But I dont know what to do.
    }
})
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your helpers functions outside of the helper object that you are passing, you can use them like any other function.

```
var firstValue = function () {
  return something;
};

var secondValue = function () {
  var fv = firstValue();
  return somethingelse;
};

Template.testTemp.helpers({
  firstValue: firstValue,
  secondValue: secondValue
});
```

Comment: I found that `secondValue = function () { firstValue = Template.testTemp.firstValue(); }` can work too!

Answer (score 0):

You can hack a call to a template helper with:

```
Template.tplName.__helpers.get('helper').call()
```

MDG suggests using a regular function and then passing it to helpers, events and so on. See [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4732#issuecomment-121419193).