# Meteor how to call another function in current function?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a function in helpers. I want to call that function in my next function. How can I fall it ?

```
'first_func' ()
{
    return "hello";
},
'second_func' ()
{
    return this.first_func();
}
```

This is not working. I want to call first function in second one.

Thank YoU!

Comment: Are these methods of an object? And how do you call the function?

Comment: No they are not object. Just defined in Template.test.hepers({});

Comment: You are passing `{}` to the function which is an object and those functions are methods of the object. `this` is dynamic and value of it depends on how a function is called. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I don't know a good use case for this but if you really want to use it then please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17229302/4699406

Comment: Okay. What other method do you suggest ?

Comment: [This forum post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042886/how-do-you-call-a-meteor-template-helper-from-the-console-or-other-js-code) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you're trying to do this, you would not need `this`. So you would be able to call the first function like so:

```
function first_func() {
   //`this` is bound to first_func()
   return "hello";
}

function second_func () {
   //`this` is bound to second_func()
   return first_func();
}

second_func(); // returns 'hello'
```

It appears, however, that you're trying to call functions within a class or a method. I can't guess at how or why, though, so please see the answer at [Can you write nested functions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212477/can-you-write-nested-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Like @thatgibbyguy says, you can just define a function in the same file and use it. In a Meteor template helper, `this` is the *data context* of the helper, not the template instance itself.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers(
  first_func(){
    return myFunction();
  },
  second_func(){
    return myFunction();
  }
);
function myFunction(){
   return "Hello"
}
```

You can also [register a global helper](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper) which can be used from any template